# Add aliases to console_scripts inside setup()

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line, package, python-packaging

I was wondering if there is any way of specifying aliases to a command defined in console_scripts inside entry_points arg of setup().

Can I do something like this?

```py
entry_points={
          'console_scripts': ['[command,alias0,alias1,alias2]=packagename.__main__:main'],
      },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aliasing absolutely works, but not quite in the way you want it to. As long as a slight amount of code duplication is fine for you, you can do this instead:

```
entry_points={
    'console_scripts': [
        'command=packagename.__main__:main',
        'alias0=packagename.__main__:main',
        'alias1=packagename.__main__:main',
        'alias2=packagename.__main__:main'
]}
```

Comment: So that's the only way?

Comment: I'm pretty sure. There is [different ways](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#dynamic-discovery-of-services-and-plugins) to specify entrypoints, either as dictionary or as string, but all of them require you to bind aliases as explicitly as in the example i gave.

Comment: Happy to help =)